# Jolt grouping together and including new tags

Tags: specifications, jolt

I have the following input JSON and want to group the sub jsons according to device name.(Device name has to be extracted from address). Also, i want to add new tags to the new arrays formed(Each array contains jsons having that type of device name only).

I've already tried below spec but the array Name name is appearing as `deviceName` instead of custom Parameter(I don't know how to provide custom name. for example i want the array name as "Parameters"). I'm not able to extract the device name from address field.(Device Name should come as "bee"/"honey"). Also, I want to add a new field which should be there once for the new array (and not for each element).

Input Json:

```
{
    "CID": "AND",
    "parameters": [{
            "address": "abc:api:honey",
            "name": "CH1"
        },
        {
            "address": "abc:api:honey",
            "name": "CH2"
        },
        {
            "address": "abc:api:bee",
            "name": "lat"
        },
        {
            "address": "abc:api:bee",
            "name": "long"
        }
    ],
    "rNo": 1232
}
```

Expected Output:

```
[{
    "ID": "AND_1232",
    "parameters": [{
            "deviceName": "honey",
            "name": "CH1",
            "locoId": 1232,
            "CID": "AND"
        },
        {
            "deviceName": "honey",
            "name": "CH2",
            "locoId": 1232,
            "CID": "AND"
        }
    ],
    "SpData": {

    }
},
{
    "ID": "AND_1232",
    "parameters": [{
            "deviceName": "bee",
            "name": "lat",
            "locoId": 1232,
            "CID": "AND"
        },
        {
            "deviceName": "bee",
            "name": "long",
            "locoId": 1232,
            "CID": "AND"
        }
    ],
    "SpData": {

    }
}]
```

Spec I tried:

```
        [
          {
            "operation": "shift",
            "spec": {
              "parameters": {
                "*": {
                  "@(2,CID)": "&2.[&1].CID",
                  "*": "&2.[&1].&",
                  "@(2,rNo)": "&2.[&1].locoId"
                }
              }
            }
  },
          {
            "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
            "spec": {
              "ID": "=concat(@(0,CID),'_',@(0,rNo))",
              "parameters": {
                "*": {
                  "deviceName": "=substring(@(1,address),8,11)",
                  "SpData": {}
                }
              }
            }
  }, {
            "operation": "shift",
            "spec": {
              "parameters": {
                "*": {
                  "deviceName": {
                    "*": {
                      "@2": "&[]"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
  }

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will output desired results, each operation does the following respectively:

1. Add ID by concatenating CID and rNo
2. Add rNo and CID to all parameters and add deviceName (see [here](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/issues/668) for details on device name splitting).
3. Group records by deviceName using object
4. Add ID to each group
5. Convert temporary grouping to array
6. Add default SpData

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "ID": "=concat(@(1,CID),'_',@(1,rNo))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ID": "&",
      "parameters": {
        "*": {
          "address": {
            "*:*:*": {
              "$(0,3)": "parameters.[&3].deviceName"
            }
          },
          "@(0,name)": "parameters.[&].name",
          "@(2,rNo)": "parameters.[&].locoId",
          "@(2,CID)": "parameters.[&].CID"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ID": "&",
      "parameters": {
        "*": {
          "deviceName": {
            "*": {
              "@(3,[&2])": "tmp.&.parameters.[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "tmp": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,ID)": "&1.ID",
          "parameters": {
            "@": "&2.parameters"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "SpData": {}
      }
    }
  }
]
```